# Why is my arrayList selecting items that have been removed?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList, with about 80 objects, I am trying to randomly select one of the objects, assign it to another object, remove it from the array list then return the selected object. Instead I am returning objects that have already been removed.

here is my code:

```
while (!ballStorage.isEmpty()) {
    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    int arraySize = ballStorage.size();//this is 80
    for (int j = 80; j >= 0; j--) {
        while (arraySize > 0) {

            int i = rnd.nextInt(arraySize);

            ballSelected = ballStorage.get(i);
            ballStorage.remove(i);
            ballStorage.trimToSize();
            arraySize--;

            //debugging println's
            System.out.print(ballStorage);
            System.out.println("random number generated is: " + i);
            System.out.println("ball selected is: " +ballSelected);
            System.out.println("Array size is: " + arraySize);

            return ballSelected;
        }

    }
}
return ballSelected;

//output:45W,[62Bl,, 74Bl,]random number generated is: 2
  ball selected is: 16W,
  Array size is: 2
  16W,[62Bl,]random number generated is: 1
  ball selected is: 74Bl,
  Array size is: 1
  74Bl,[]random number generated is: 0
  ball selected is: 62Bl,
  Array size is: 0
```

Comment: You're returning from inside of a loop (with no condition checking), are you sure? Your while loop will never run more than once. Also, `while(size > 0) { if(size == 0)` is redundant, because the if condition will never be true.

Comment: That won't re-select the same entry twice. It could seem to, if the ArrayList contains duplicates. But there are a number of issues with the code. You're doing two loops but returning from the first iteration of them both, making them both pointless. You have a loop condition (`while (arraySize > 0)` where the first statement inside the body checks for an impossible condition (`if (arraySize == 0)`; but you know it's not 0, it's `> 0` or the `while` would have ended). We can't tell you what's wrong from this fragment of the code. We'd need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (!ballStorage.isEmpty()) {

        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();


        int i = rnd.nextInt(ballStorage.size());

        ballSelected = ballStorage.get(i);
        ballStorage.remove(i);
        ballStorage.trimToSize();





         System.out.print(ballStorage);
         System.out.println("random number generated is: " + i);
         System.out.println("ball selected is: " +ballSelected);
         System.out.println("Array size is: " + arraySize);

  }


    return ballSelected;
```

I can't understand why you return inside a loop. This is the reason why your
loop executing 1 time.

But i suppose you want to return the BallSelected every time so:

```
class BallStorage implements Iterator<Ball>, Iterable<Ball> {

     private int size;
     private Random random;
     private ArrayList<Ball> balls;


     public BallStorage() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.balls = new ArrayList<>();
        this.random = new Random();
     }

     public void add(Ball ball) {
       this.size++;
       balls.add(ball);
     } 

     Ball next() {

        Ball b = balls.get(random.nextInt(size));
        balls.remove(b);
        this.size--;
    return b;
     }

     boolean hasNext() {
        return size > 0;
     }

     Iterator<Ball> iterator() {
        return this;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         //Create Balls and add them in ballStorage object

         for(Ball ball: ballStorage)
             System.out.println("ball selected is: " +ball);
     }

}
```

Comment: I need to return the ball selected every time while shortening the array, I tried it with an if statement but the arraylist returns to the original size. Thanks for the input this helped!